# Relative namespaces in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces

Are namespaces in typescript relative? When i try the following code.

```
namespace a.b.c {
  export function sayHello() {
    b.g.h.sayHello();
  }
}

namespace b.g.h {
  export function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}

a.b.c.sayHello();
```

I get an error that "Property 'g' does not exist on type 'typeof b'."

Is there a way to say typescript that 'b' is the root and not a child of the "current" namespace?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because when inside `a`, accessing `b` will give you what's in the current scope and that's `a.b`.
The only way for you to do that is to access the root `b` from the window object:

```
namespace a.b.c {
    export function sayHello() {
        window.b.g.h.sayHello();
    }
}
```

But then you'll also need to add the definitions to the window object:

```
interface Window {
    b: {
        g: {
            h: {
                sayHello(): void;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Window%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20g%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20h%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sayHello()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20a.b.c%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20sayHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.b.g.h.sayHello()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20b.g.h%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20function%20sayHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.b.c.sayHello()%3B))

Another option is to wrap `b` in another namespace:

```
namespace a.b.c {
    export function sayHello() {
        wrapper.b.g.h.sayHello();
    }
}

namespace wrapper.b.g.h {
    export function sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20a.b.c%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20sayHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wrapper.b.g.h.sayHello()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20wrapper.b.g.h%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20sayHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.b.c.sayHello()%3B))